# cannot reach a file on server though I exposed using express

Tags: node.js, express, nodejs-server

In my project I need to store some text files dynamically and end user should be able to download them from browser. I know the best way is using object store like MINIO or S3 but unfortunately the only way I have is to use in memory storage. So what I am trying to do is: I made a public folder and I exposed it using the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//setting middleware
app.use(express.static( 'public')); //Serves resources from public folder


var server = app.listen(5000);
```

it is as simple as that. Then for testing just to make sure I can download and reach a file I created a public folder with t.txt file in it and when I try:

```
http://localhost:5000/public/t.txt
```

I get

[image]

So why am I not getting it? Also is what I am trying to achieve will be a good match to scenario and is it doable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're not specifying a path in `app.use()`, your app will serve the contents of the directory you're pointing to in `express.static()` on the *root* path. Try this:

```
http://localhost:5000/t.txt
```

That said, if you want it to be accessible at `/public/t.txt`, just specify the path:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))
```

Answer (score 1):

At first use the following line of code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

This means that your home directory for static HTML pages is in the "public" folder. Note that the "__dirname" points to the directory of the current js file.

After that, call the following URL from the browser or POSTMAN:

```
http://localhost:5000/t.txt
```

As you can see, there is no need to write `http://localhost:5000/public/t.txt` referring to the "public" folder because you have already specified that in the app.use line.